# "page not found nginx/1.4.4" errors on every page except homepage

Tags: php, nginx, centos

I'm getting "page not found" errors on nearly every page. I searched Google, where it was suggested that there could be something wrong with nginx's URL_rewrite.

I have already changed `nginx/conf/nginx.config.default` like this

```
 location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
```

but it's still not working.

Server system: Centos 7
nginx: 1.4.4
PHP version: 5.5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is in your document root create two files.

The first one call test.html and in the file write the following:

> This is a test

Then create one called test.php with the following in it:

```
<?php

// Show all information, defaults to INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

?>
```

Navigate to each on your browser like

http://example.com/test.html and http://example.com/test.php

My guess is that the html will load and the php wont.

This is due to php and nginx not having the correct permissions for the files.

First thing is to do the following command:

> chown -R nginx:nginx documentroot

And keep doing that command adding /* each timne until you get an error.

In your nginx.conf file you need to ensure you have the following:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Then go to /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

and ensure the following are set to this:

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
```

This should fix the problem.

Comment: Glad that worked for you, my advice is save the conf files for both php-fpm and nginx so that you can reuse the correct settings whenever you need them.

Answer (score 0):

> I have already changed nginx/conf/nginx.config.default like this

Seems that file is the original config file not the file that work, try to find
`nginx.config` file without the `.default` extension.

If u did not find it try to copy the default in a new file with name `nginx.config`